# Laravel Valet installing extension on older php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I am working on a legacy app and it's running on PHP 7.4. I was able to isolate the app to run php 7.4 but I get an error saying Install or enable PHP's imap extension I installed it and it should be enabled but it's not working. Any idea on why? When I run: valet php -m | grep imap it returns empty but when I run it without valet, I can see it's running. I am thinking that it's installed on the main version of php which is 8.1

I also tried unlinking 8.1 and linking 7.4 and then running the brew install but it doesn't change eanything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Valet will install php from https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php so to add an extension you can use https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions

So in your example, run:

`brew install shivammathur/extensions/imap@7.4`

You can check this worked:

`valet php -i | grep imap`